# "private final static long serialVersionUID" in JAXB generated class

Tags: jaxb

I am using globalBindings in JAXB to generate Serializable classes.

```
<jaxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:simple />
    <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

The uid attribute is generated in the java classes as the following:

```
private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I understand that "final static" and "static final" are the same and the generated serializable classes can also be compiled. But we are getting error from SonarQube of using "final static" instead of "static final".

We are currently manually changing the attribute to "static final" to bypass the SonarQube issue. But can anyone suggest if it is possible to have JAXB to generate "static final" instead?

We are using JAXB2 and this is the pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <execution>
    <id>someID</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration> 
    <sources>        
      <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/some.xsd</source>
    </sources>
    <xjbSources>
        <xjbSource>src/main/resources/some.xjb</xjbSource>
    </xjbSources>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it is not really reasonable to check the *generated* code.

If SonarQube complains about `private final static` but not `private static final`, just ignore it. It does not matter, especially not in the generated code.

Now, to answer your question - you can write an XJC plugin which would generate `static final` instead. Here's an [article](http://www.archive.ricston.com/blog/xjc-plugin/) on it. You can find further examples in [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/basic).

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) which is a package of XJC plugins.